# SQL - Whole Records Being Cleared Out Through ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Tags: asp.net, sql, webforms

I'm part of a team building a large ASP.NET Web Forms application, and have recently gotten complaints that some records are being "cleared out" after being created -- in this case they create an "inventory" item, save it, and then perhaps after editing some of the data and re-saving, all of the fields are suddenly blank.

I realize that this could be some faulty logic on the save, in which case it will be difficult for you to offer insight, but we've never come across this particular issue before, and haven't really touched the logic. I'm wondering if anyone has some insight into what could possibly be going on, if it's possible that something sporadically happens on the client which makes the values of the input fields blank or unreadable...? I don't know, I'm a bit in the dark and frustrated because I can't reproduce the behavior, and we're losing a bunch of data.

Thanks in advance for any bit of direction or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Related issues in WebForms are often caused by logic related to Page.IsPostBack and values being reset.

Without code it's hard to say; I'd suggest adding some temporary code to log the posted data (and function calls down the line to the database writes). Without logging you're blind.